# What eloquent relationship should I use in this case?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I'm really confused in which relationship I should use for this kind of data structure. To make everything understandable I have this script system where you make a section then you attach a question to that section and question has many options(answers) and every option has a target section to go to if a user clicks that option now that works and got that everything figured out. But I want to make question and options to be reusable from any sections but I can't do that because options target section must be different from every sections if that make sense. I'm just really confused in which is the best way to do it, I can do it dirty but I want to do it the best and clean way.

Basically
I currently have

Section Col
name, body

Question Col
name, question, section_id

Option Col
name, value, question_id, target_section

I want question to be reusable on any section but I want Options target_section field to be different from every section.

Comment: Plz provide codes hou've tried

Comment: Kind tough to discern with all the run on sentences, but it sounds like you're describing a many-to-many between options and sections.

Comment: what do you mean exactly when you say "But I want to make question and options to be reusable from any sections but I can't do that because options target section must be different from every sections if that make sense"

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend you to make hasMany relation of the section with the question and then make a one to one relation of the option of the question and section and also make hasMany relation for the questions and options to it. i can explain you better if you can post code or related data for the things you want to achieve.

Comment: Basically
I currently have

Section Col
name, body

Question Col
name, question, section_id

Option Col
name, value, question_id, target_section

I want question to be reusable on any section but I want Options target_section field to be different from every section.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't fully understand your question, I can try to help the best I can until you explain a bit more about the end result you're trying to achieve.

You could set up your database and models like the following...

---

**Sections Table**
which would have the columns:

```
id, name, body
```

The model would look like this:

**Section.php (Section model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Section extends Model
{
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Questions');
    }
}
```

---

**Questions Table**
Which would have the columns:

```
id, section_id, name, body
```

and your Questions Model could would look something like this:

**Questions.php (Questions model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Questions extends Model
{
    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Options');
    }

    public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Section');
    }
}
```

---

Finally, your options table
**Options Table**
which would have the columns:

```
id, questions_id, section_id, name, body
```

with a model something similar to:

**Options.php (Options model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Options extends Model
{
    public function question()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Questions', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

Relationships like this would allow you to do things like:

```
$question->options
```

to get the options associated with that question

```
$section->question
```

to get the question associated with that section

```
$question->section
```

to get the section associated with that question